# C# WPF Window Margin

Tags: c#, wpf

How to make the window larger than my screen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZPDI.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hardcode it just put the needed size

```
<Window [....] Title="Test" Height="497" Width="704" FontSize="25" Icon="icon.ico">
```

If you need to calculate it for different screen sizes then go in code and:

```
this.Height = 123;
this.Width= 123;
```

PS:  there is also Top and Left values that you might have to edit - to center the window properly

Comment: I installed as you said, but it turns out something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJuqy.png I also forgot to say, I have a trace of parameters itle="MainWindow" MinHeight="1466" MinWidth="868" Margin="1100,0,0,0" WindowState="Maximized" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" WindowStyle="None"

Comment: Then you need to set Top and Left to negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the code-behind:

```cs
double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
double windowWidth = this.Width;
double windowHeight = this.Height;
this.Left = (screenWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
this.Top = (screenHeight / 2) - (windowHeight / 2);
```

This would center your window w.r.t the screen.

Comment: I have a trace of parameters WindowState =" Maximized " WindowStyle =" None " and because of them, my program cannot move to the left and up

Comment: But if your window is greater than the screen, surely you don't need to set `WindowState="Maximized"`, right?!